# How to disable FAB icon on load effect when it is a part of MUI V5 speedDial?

Tags: material-ui

I have the following component. The issue is that, on load, the icon quickly transforms from a small to its original size. I want to stop this behavior, but it is not working. How can I achieve this?

```js
// Parent 
const StyledSpeedDial = styled(SpeedDial)(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[300] : '#4A4545' /* back-ground image on paper */,
  width: 45,
  borderRadius: 25,
  zIndex: 12,
  // Note: transition style works here...
  transitionDuration: '0.4s',
  transform: 'none',
}));

// Fab 
const StyledSpeedDialIcon = styled(SpeedDialIcon)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 36,
  height: 36,
  transition: 'none',
  transform: 'none',
  '& .MuiSpeedDialIcon-icon': {
    transition: 'none',
    transform: 'none',
  },
  '& .MuiSpeedDialIcon-iconWithOpenIconOpen': {
    transition: 'none',
    transform: 'none',
  },
}));

// Component 
  <StyledSpeedDial
        ariaLabel='SpeedDial'
        FabProps={{
          disabled: disableComponentOn,
          sx: {
            transition: 'none',
            transform: 'none',
          },
        }}
        icon={
          <StyledSpeedDialIcon
            icon={
              <ExpandMoreIcon
                sx={{
                  transition: 'none',
                  transform: 'none',
                }}
              />
            }
          />
        }
        onClose={handleClose}
        onClick={handleOpen}
        open={open}
        direction={'down'}
        sx={{ ...(!open && { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }) }}
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition is applied in the `MuiSpeedDial-fab` class. In your `StyledSpeedDial` component you can override this class:

```js
const StyledSpeedDial = styled(SpeedDial)(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "absolute",
  backgroundColor:
    theme.palette.mode === "light"
      ? theme.palette.grey[300]
      : "#4A4545" /* back-ground image on paper */,
  width: 45,
  borderRadius: 25,
  zIndex: 12,
  "& .MuiSpeedDial-fab": {
    transition: "none !important",
  },
}));
```

Comment: I don't want to push !important; I want control over the main class that is handling the initial transition.